# async Telnet Server data receiving issues

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, protocol-buffers

I am writing a telnet server using the `async Begin/End` methods. The issue that I am having is determining what within my buffer is actual data and what is not. Network coding is a bit new to me, but I've tried to research this and have not been able to find a answer.

```
public bool Start(IGame game)
{
    // Get our server address information.
    IPHostEntry serverHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPEndPoint serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, this.Port);

    // Instance the server socket, bind it to a port and begin listening for connections.
    this._ServerSocket = new Socket(serverEndPoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    this._ServerSocket.Bind(serverEndPoint);
    this._ServerSocket.Listen(this.MaxQueuedConnections);

    this._ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Connect), this._ServerSocket);
    return true;
}

private void Connect(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var player = new BasePlayer();
    try
    {
        player.Game = this.Game;
        player.Connection = this._ServerSocket.EndAccept(result);

        lock (this.Connections)
        {
            this.Connections.Add(player);
        }

        // Pass all of the data handling for the player to itself.
        player.Connection.BeginReceive(player.Buffer, 0, player.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(player.ReceiveData), player);

        // Fetch the next incoming connection.
        this._ServerSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Connect), this._ServerSocket);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

and then the player.ReceiveData..

```
public void ReceiveData(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int bytesRead = this.Connection.EndReceive(result);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        // TODO: Parse data received by the user.

        //Queue the next receive data.
        this.Connection.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, this.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), this);
        var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Disconnect(result);
    }
}
```

So when I call `BeginReceive`, I need to provide a buffer of a predetermined size. In doing that, I end up with unused bytes in my buffer array. They all have the value of 0, so I am assuming that I can loop through the array and build a new one starting at index 0 and working until I hit a value of 0.

I imagine there is a better way to do this? Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how I should determine what the data is within my buffer or perhaps a way that I can do this without having to use a predetermined buffer size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when call BeginReceive, I need to provide a buffer of a predetermined size. In doing that, I end up with unused bytes in my buffer array. They all have the value of 0, so I am assuming that I can loop through the array and build a new one starting at index 0 and working until I hit a value of 0.

No, that's not what you should do. Instead, in your callback (`ReceiveData`) you're already calling [`EndReceive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - and the result of that is the number of bytes you read. *That's* how much of the buffer you should use.

However, you should copy the data you've read out of the buffer *before* you call `BeginReceive` again, otherwise you may end up with the next bit of data overwriting the just-read data before you get to use it.

So something like:

```
string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
Connection.BeginReceive(this.Buffer, 0, this.BufferSize, SocketFlags.None,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveData), this);
```

I would *not* suggest that you use `Encoding.Default` to convert the bytes to text - instead, you should decide which encoding you're using, and stick to that. If you use an encoding which isn't always one-byte-per-character, you'll end up in a slightly trickier situation, as then you might end up receiving a buffer with *part* of a character. At that point you need to keep a [`Decoder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can maintain state about partial characters read.

Comment: I probably wasn't really clear when I made that statement. I was referring to when I invoke BeginReceive, the required parameter is for a set-sized buffer.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: Yes, that is a requirement - just like calling `Stream.Read`.

Comment: In My `ReceiveData` I am actually already calling EndReceive and capturing the buffer size (although I didn't realize that's what the value was). So to clarify my original question some, if I have the data in my buffer, and I am given the number of bytes read by EndReceive, is there a way to split my existing buffer into a new array pulling just the received bytes?

Comment: I was wondering if there was something along the lines of `byte[] receivedData = this.Buffer.Range[0, receivedDataSize];`

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: Well you can create a new array (`new byte[size]`) and then use `Array.Copy` or `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the data. There's no existing method in the framework to do that, but you can create your own method trivially. However, given that you're converting it into a string, why not just use `Encoding.GetString(byte[], int, int)`?

Comment: @JohnSkeet: I had just found that overload for GetString actually. Thanks for pointing it out. That fixes my problem for the most part. However when I receive the data, it looks like the part of it gets removed at the beginning. If I type "This is a test" in my telnet client and send it, my server receives "\r\nis is a test" when using GetString(this.Buffer, 0, receivedSize);

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger: It's possible that you're seeing some control codes before text - but with your original code, it's also possible that you were seeing the problem I mentioned in my answer, where you were reading into the buffer again before you actually fetched the text.

Comment: I was able to resolve that last question. I had my byte to string conversion taking place after my second BeginReceive method call so it was picking up extra stuff. Moving the byte - string conversion prior to invoking BeginReceive again fixed the problem and returned my text properly formatted. Thanks a ton for the help!